# UILabel strike/cross out

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

Has anyone a idea how can i strike/cross out a UILable with Anmimation - like a "Todolist function"?

In Objective C.. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a custom UILabel with a UIImage added as a subview. Though I think you'll want to do it in a custom UITableCell if you want a nice look, scrolling as iPhone users expect, etc.